# Defining an invertible linear map between these vector spaces

Tags: linear-algebra

I am going through the proof of theorem 3.60 in Axler's Linear Algebra Done Right, 3rd ed., which states the following:

> Suppose $v_1, \ldots, v_n$ is a basis of $V$ and $w_1, \ldots, w_n$ is a basis of $W$/ Then, $\mathcal{M}$ is an isomorphism between $\mathcal{L}(V, W)$ and $\mathbf{F}^{m,n}$

Proof:

It is easy to show that $\mathcal{M}(S + T) = \mathcal{M}(S) + \mathcal{M}(T)$, and $\mathcal{M}(\lambda S) = \lambda\mathcal{M}( S)$, for $S,T \in \mathcal{L}(V,W)$ and $\lambda \in \mathbf{F}$. It follows that $\mathcal{M}$ is linear.

It remains to show that $\mathcal{M}$ is injective and surjective. We begin by proving injectivity. Let $T \in \mathcal{L}(V,W)$, and $\mathcal{M}(T) = 0$. It follows from the definition of a matrix that $Tv_k = 0\; \text{for}\; k = 1, \ldots, n$. Since $v_1, \ldots, v_n$ is a basis of $V$, this implies that $T = 0$, and therefore $\mathcal{M}$ is injective.***

We now show that $\mathcal{M}$ is surjective. Suppose $A \in \mathbf{F}^{m,n}$ and $T \in \mathcal{L}(V,W)$ such that

\begin{equation*}
Tv_k = \sum_{j = 1}^{m} A_{j,k} w_j,\; \text{for}\; k= 1, \ldots, n
\end{equation*}

It follows from the definition of a matrix that $\mathcal{M}(T) = A$, and therefore the $\operatorname{range} \mathcal{M} = \mathbf{F}^{m,n}$

$$\tag*{$\blacksquare$}$$

My question is what is the invertible linear map being defined between these vector spaces, is it this?

$\mathcal{M}:\mathcal{L}(V,W) \rightarrow \textbf{F}^{m,n}$

defined by $M(T)=A$? where $A \in \textbf{F}^{m,n}$?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, $\mathcal M$ is the invertible map. It is assigning the *matrix of the linear map $T$* to $T$, which satisfies
$$\mathcal M(T) \cdot [x]_{(v_i)}\ =\ [T(x)]_{(w_i)}$$
for all $x\in V$, where $[x]$ denotes the coordinate (column) vector of $x$, coordinated in the given basis.

$\mathcal M(T)$ can be specifically described as the matrix whose $j$th column contains the $w_i$-coordinates of $T(v_j)$.

Comment: So you cannot define the map as $M(T)=A$?

Comment: You can once you tell what is $A$.

Comment: No, that can be an alternative definition of the matrix of $T$. Well, $\mathcal M$ is an isomorphism (linear one-to-one correspondence) between the linear maps $V\to W$ and real $n\times m$ matrices.

Comment: I think the root of my confusion was the solution given in the book(above) does not actually define the transformation explicitly like I have seen in most isomorphism problems. Like for instance an isomorphism from $\mathcal{P}_2(F)$ to $\textbf{F}^3$ can be defined by $T(a+bx+cx^2)=(a,b,c)$ how would you go about defining a map between the given vector spaces above, that is simpler than using your notation? I was thinking $M(T)=A$ would suffices since $M$ will map the transformation in $\mathcal{L}(V,W)$  into the matrix $A$ in $\textbf{F}^{m,n}$? Is this not correct?

Comment: I mean $[x]_{(v_i)}$ as the coordinate vector $\pmatrix{\alpha_1\\ \vdots \\ \alpha_n}$ consisting of the coefficients in the unique linear combination $x=\sum_i\alpha_iv_i$.

Comment: If you denote $\mathcal M(T)$ by $A$ and swallow the bases from the subscripts, we can write $$A\cdot[x] =[T(x)]\,. $$ I assume it was covered previously in the book (maybe with other notation), that this property uniquely determines the matrix $A$. This property *is* the correspondence between $A$ and $T$.

Comment: We can't really tell it more explicitly.. Now the input of our function is itself a linear *funtion*, and is not as specific as a tuple of real numbers (though both types of entities can be added to one another or multiplied by reals).

Comment: The map $\mathcal{M}$ is explicitly and cleanly defined in the book; see 3.32.